# How to Decompile Java

Tags: java, decompiling

I would like a simple way to decompile Java. I want to examine the conversions and modifications that the javac compiler makes on my code. What would be some good products and what would be the good/bad of them.

Comment: Lots of starting points? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=decompiler+java

Comment: The compiler **never** modifies your code, it translates your code to java byte code (which is stored in a `.class`) file.

Comment: Its worth noting that the compiler does very few optimisations and doesn't give you much of an idea what the JVM will do with it at run time. It is in the JVM all the significant optimiations are made.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick and dirty, use the `javap` that ships with the JDK.

```
javap -c test
Compiled from "test.java"
public class test extends java.lang.Object{
public test();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[])   throws java.lang.Exception;
  Code:
   0:   ldc #2; //String CR_ABC_DEF_GHI
   2:   astore_1
   3:   ldc #3; //String TYPE=Eligibility Only|CLIENT_ID=62|EMPLOYER_ID=0|LOCATION_ID=0|PLAN_ID=all|FREQUENCY=52|FILE=null|FILETYPE=C|PROCESSTOLAUNCH=10|PROCESSTOLAUNCHSTATUS=100|SCHEDULE_ID=29837d692f4c43e786f1097fab7c360c
   5:   astore_2
   6:   ldc #4; //String \|
   8:   astore_3
   9:   ldc #5; //String FILE_NAME_TEMPLATE
   11:  astore  4
   13:  ldc #6; //String FILE
   15:  astore  5
   17:  new #7; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   20:  dup
   21:  invokespecial   #8; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   24:  aload_3
   25:  invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   28:  aload   4
   30:  invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   33:  ldc #10; //String =
   35:  invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   38:  ldc #11; //String [^
   40:  invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   43:  aload_3
   44:  invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   47:  ldc #12; //String ]*
   49:  invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   52:  aload_3
   53:  invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   56:  invokevirtual   #13; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   59:  astore  6
   61:  new #7; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   64:  dup
   65:  invokespecial   #8; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   68:  aload_3
   69:  invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   72:  aload   5
   74:  invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   77:  ldc #10; //String =
   79:  invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   82:  ldc #11; //String [^
   84:  invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   87:  aload_3
   88:  invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   91:  ldc #12; //String ]*
   93:  invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   96:  aload_3
   97:  invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   100: invokevirtual   #13; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   103: astore  7
   105: new #7; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   108: dup
   109: invokespecial   #8; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   112: aload_3
   113: invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   116: aload   4
   118: invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   121: ldc #10; //String =
   123: invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   126: aload_1
   127: invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   130: aload_3
   131: invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   134: invokevirtual   #13; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   137: astore  8
   139: aload_2
   140: aload   6
   142: aload   8
   144: invokevirtual   #14; //Method java/lang/String.replaceAll:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
   147: aload   7
   149: aload   8
   151: invokevirtual   #14; //Method java/lang/String.replaceAll:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
   154: astore  9
   156: getstatic   #15; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   159: new #7; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   162: dup
   163: invokespecial   #8; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   166: ldc #16; //String before = 
   168: invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   171: aload_2
   172: invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   175: invokevirtual   #13; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   178: invokevirtual   #17; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   181: getstatic   #15; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   184: new #7; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   187: dup
   188: invokespecial   #8; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   191: ldc #18; //String pattern1 = 
   193: invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   196: aload   6
   198: invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   201: invokevirtual   #13; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   204: invokevirtual   #17; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   207: getstatic   #15; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   210: new #7; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   213: dup
   214: invokespecial   #8; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   217: ldc #19; //String pattern2 = 
   219: invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   222: aload   7
   224: invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   227: invokevirtual   #13; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   230: invokevirtual   #17; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   233: getstatic   #15; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   236: new #7; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   239: dup
   240: invokespecial   #8; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   243: ldc #20; //String replace = 
   245: invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   248: aload   8
   250: invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   253: invokevirtual   #13; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   256: invokevirtual   #17; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   259: getstatic   #15; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   262: new #7; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   265: dup
   266: invokespecial   #8; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   269: ldc #21; //String after = 
   271: invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   274: aload   9
   276: invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   279: invokevirtual   #13; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   282: invokevirtual   #17; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   285: return

}
```

Comment: This will give you a better idea of what the compiler is doing. As the decompiler will try its best to turn this back into sensible code, hiding alot of the details.

Answer (score 2):

The best one is probably jad:

http://www.varaneckas.com/jad

If you use Eclipse, you can use the JadClipse plugin, for a more ergonomic interface:

http://jadclipse.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 1):

I have found [this tool](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Another java decompiler – AndroChef Java Decompiler is available: http://www.neshkov.com/ac_decompiler.html

Answer (score 0):

I've used JAD and can atest to it's usefulness.

Just as a heads up though that any de-compiled code is most likely going to be free of any comments, and if the code is obfuscated then decompiling won't really get you any where. It will still look like jibberish.